# @media screen is not working. What can i do?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div of 200px width and 100px height. I want to resize this div with `@media`. But `@media` does not work. So what can I do?

```
.abc{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
@media (max-width: 752px) and (min-width: 1024px){
  .abc{
     width:500px; 
     height:500px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition could never be true. Try `(min-width: 752px) and (max-width: 1024px)` or `(max-width: 752px) or (min-width: 1024px)` (depending on what you want to achieve).

Answer (score 1):

You have set your max width to 752 pixels and min-width to 1024 pixels. swap those. right now you have it so that your media device must be smaller than 753 and at the same time larger than 1023.

Comment: It is very easy to miss simple things like that -- especially when the code is not broken but the numbers are off, so no error message happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 752px) and (max-width: 1024px){
  .abc{width:500px; height:500px;}
}
```

your max and min are swapped

Comment: @Rocky: don't forget to accept one of these answers, if they worked for you. To do so, click on the tick mark to the left of the answer you wish to accept, so it changes colour.